# How to correctly set permissions on a folder so nginx can read from the directory and files

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, openresty

I am referencing my SSL files that are stored under:

```
/etc/letsecrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem
/etc/letsecrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
```

From within nginx I need to be able to read to those files, I will be using LUA code to read from there also potentially but it should be the same permissions.

My nginx is running under the nobody account.

Currently I am getting a permissions issue.

Is there a command I can change all the files under the /etc/letsencrypt/live folder?

I know there is chmod, but am confused if I should be changing this for owner or group.